# Double binding angular 2 with SVG

Tags: svg, data-binding, double, angular

I am writing an Angular 2 application, And i can't understand why Angular can not properly work with <svg>. When i try to make SVG elements active with angular, i see errors in console.

```
   <rect x={{rect.x}} y={{rect.y}} width={{rect.width}} height={{rect.height}} fill={{rect.fill}} stroke={{rect.stroke}} />
<path [d]="M0,0 v rect.height h rect.width v- rect.height z" />
```

Comment: Some actual code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish or some actual error message you get would be very helpful. You can edit your original answer instead of adding comments. Code in comments is usually hard to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work

```
<rect [attr.x]="rect.x" [attr.y]="rect.y" [attr.width]="rect.width" [attr.height]="rect.height"
 [attr.fill]="rect.fill" [attr.stroke]="rect.stroke" />
```

`x={{rect.x}}` (equivalent to `[x]="rect.x"` is property binding syntax but these SVG attributes need attribute binding.

Comment: Thank  for your answer but this method dosen't work in the path element for inject many variable into the d attribute like this:
`<path  [d]="M0,0 v rect.height  h rect.width v- rect.height  z" />`

Comment: You're obviously using different code than in the your original question. Can you please edit your question and add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Comment: Remember that with [] binding, the RHS must be an valid JS expression. So you must re-write: `<path [d]="M0,0 v rect.height ... z" />`  like this: `<path [attr.d]=" 'M0.0 v ' + rect.height + ... + 'z' "/>`