# Angular 2 svg - pass height and width dynamically

Tags: angular, svg

I am using Angular 2 and to create a donut chart I did my implementation through svg.
Height and width been passed directly so far:

**component's html**

```
<svg height="200px" width="200px"> blah_blah_blah_blah_ </svg>
```

What I want is to pass those values as inputs from the main component. So, lets say that on html I call the component like:

**main HTML**

```
<donut-chart [Height]="200" [Width]="200"></donut-chart>
```

**Component.js code**

```
@Input() Height: number = 100;
@Input() Width: number = 100;
```

So, my problem is how to pass those inputs into the **component's html**.

`<svg height="Height" width="Width">` doesn't work in that case.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

SVG doesn't support property-binding, it requires attribute-binding

```
<svg attr.height.px="{{Height}}" attr.width="{{Width}}px"> blah_blah_blah_blah_ </svg>
```

or

```
<svg [attr.height.px]="Height" attr.width="{{Width}}px"> blah_blah_blah_blah_ </svg>
```

See also

- [Angular 2 data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes/34542844#34542844)
- [Double binding angular 2 with SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511929/double-binding-angular-2-with-svg/34513219#34513219)
- [Bind Angular2 values in SVG linear gradient stop offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073950/bind-angular2-values-in-svg-linear-gradient-stop-offset/41073962#41073962)
- [Angular2 SVG xlink:href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082657/angular2-svg-xlinkhref/35082700#35082700)

Comment: Why not `[attr.height]="Height"`?

Comment: Sure, if you want to pass the `px` to the `Height` and `Width` variable values, but the question doesn't indicate that, and I prefer `attr.height="{{Height}}px"` over `[attr.height]="Height + 'px'"` (interpolation instead of `+`), but that is a matter of preference.

Comment: quick and clear, worked for me! Thank you @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: `attr.width.px="{{ Width }}"` is a nice shortcut IMHO, or even better `[attr.width.px]="Width"`

Comment: @MateoTibaquirá thanks for the hint. String concatenation was a poor suggestion. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I just tried and it seems that the `px` is not needed anymore (actually didn't work when I tried). This worked: `<svg [attr.width]="Width" [attr.height]="Height" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...
</svg>`

Answer (score 0):

Width and height are simple component input properties. Seems to me there is no need to handle adding 'px' behind the values:

```
<svg
[attr.width]="width"
[attr.height]="height"
>
```